# Firebase re-authenticate using PhoneNumberProvider

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

To delete user the user has to be recently authenticated ... I am using Phone number authentication and looking at the example in the docs:  https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user

I need to get the credential of the user which requires 2 parameters: verification Id and SMS code which are fetched from authenticating the user in the first place ... so is there another way to fetch them or I have to send a verification code once more as I did when the user was first authenticated ?

Comment: You have to send it again (by design, it is useless and undermines this mechanism if this data is stored). In Android, you may end up being instantly validated without have to ask the user to provide the SMS code again.

Comment: Would like to see an example if possible, having problems with it myself